# How to i solve Error In installing Fastai using pip

Tags: python, pip, fast-ai

```
 error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\umath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\Jay Surana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\Jay Surana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt /Tcbuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalartypes.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalartypes.obj" failed with exit status 2
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure

      Encountered error while trying to install package.

      numpy

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

This is the error i am getting, i cant install fastai, i have installed all the requirements.

Comment: what version of python and what version of pip are you using?

Comment: I see from the stacktrace that you are using python 3.10